# Change date every 56 rows in excel

Tags: excel

my objective is to have the same date repeated in the first 56 rows and then to vary to the next day in row 57.
That is:
if I start with date 8/31/2013 I expect to have this same date in the following 56 rows and then change it in 57 to 9/01/2013.
So far I have been working with this `formula`:

**=IF(MOD(ROW(),56)=1,OFFSET(B2,-56,-1)+1,"")**

I got to have the dates every 56 rows but still, I need to fill row 2-55 with the same date. Is there any formula or VBA code that helps me do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In B1 put your desired start date.  Then in B2 put and copy down:

```
 =$B$1+INT((ROW()-1)/56)
```

[image]